# Emails response are not getting mapped to a case

Tags: apex, email2case

I am trying to map response of email to the case.
I have created below formula field on case for reference Id :

```
"ref:_"&LEFT( $Organization.Id , 4)&"0"&RIGHT( $Organization.Id , 4)&"._"&LEFT(Id , 4)&"0"&RIGHT(Id , 5)&":ref""
```

I have created an email template and mapped above created reference Id field in subject and body of email template. I am selecting this email template while sending email from case.
When I replying on some email, then that email is not getting mapped to the case.
Could anyone please tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Is the “[Disable Ref ID and Transition to New Email Threading Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389648&type=1)” release update enabled?

Comment: Hi @Swetha, I cannot see that feature under release updates.